# How to remove unused Clicked event from C# project

Tags: c#-3.0

I am newbie in C#. while working in Windows Forms Designer if any controls get double-clicked by mistake it places the clicked event on the Form.cs (ie: private void UserAddBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e). how can I remove all the references of this event while staying in Forms designer or w/o going thru manual removal.

Thanks in advance....

Comment: one small comment on your question too, if you use a few more meaningful tags like #winforms #designer, etc you will likely get more responses

Answer (score 7):

You can clear the event handler by deleting it from the properties dialog.

Go to the events tab and find the double click event. You can then delete the event handler from there.

Comment: The person who posted the question wanted to know how.  To do it you select the handler in the properties grid, right click it, choose reset; as answered by agleno.

Answer (score 3):

if you select the item you want to remove in the form designer, then right click on the lightning bolt and click "reset" it works for me. I couldn't make it work as explained above. I'm using  Visual studio express 2013 V12 - Update 4.

Answer (score 1):

In the **designer** view, click undo (Ctrl + Z) - this will undo the generated event handler in the code-behind as well as all bindings to the event handler in the .designer.cs autogenerated.  Do not perform the undo in the event handler codebehind, because this will remove the event handler, but leave the bindings to it.

NOTE: If you add any code to the event handler, then undo will only remove the bindings - the event handler will get left behind.  This is to make sure you don't lose anything you added that might be important.

Comment: That doesn't work well if you have done anything else in the designer view because undo undoes things in order not by selection.  And even worse if you have closed the IDE and reopened, then there isn't any undo information.

Answer (score 0):

I am privy to doing this myself lol. However, it is quite simple (I am using Visual Studio 2017). Delete the unused event and try to run while not debugging. Select no and look at the bottom where it lists the errors. Double click the red "X". Visual Studio will direct you to the next error. Delete that and you should be good to go (Should be a .Click event handler). Whether this works in all scenarios this simply I am not sure but if you have no code in that block then there should not be too much more complexity.

Answer (score 0):

Go to the event handler -> Find All References -> go to the reference and delete it. Then delete the event handler.